# More Synchronized Mark-As-Read Functionality

Tags: feature-request, notifications, profile-page, inbox

When a comment comes in on one of my posts, I get the red inbox showing up on the "Recent inbox messages" icon just to the right of my avatar-plus-stats. That's all very fine. I can click on the inbox and quickly navigate to the comments on my post. I think it would be nice if, after doing so, (so the comments are now read) if I click on my avatar-plus-stats, the "responses" tab should not show up as having unread messages - they're the same messages I just read. The same thing happens to reputation. If I look at the reputation in the "Recent achievements" button, there's no need for it to be unread in the "reputation" tab when I click my avatar-plus-stats button.

Could these two areas be better coordinated? If I read in one, the other should update, right?

Not entirely sure if this is more of a bug or more of a feature request.

Comment: I have added ([meta-tag:inbox]) tag since you are asking about functionality of the inbox. I was considering also whether ([meta-tag:notifications]) and perhaps ([meta-tag:profile-page]) could be suitable...?

Comment: I will add that this feature request is marked as ([meta-tag:status-declined]): [Remove responses from Responses tab once they've been read in Inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102153). This post seems related too: [The StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ says I've got replies, but I've already viewed those](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67987) (and maybe also some of the [other posts linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/67987) might be of interest.) Of course, it is possible that you can find a few more posts related to this on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: @MartinSleziak: Thanks for the link. I can understand the answer there, though I still find it a bit annoying.